# Internet Dropping out on Toshiba Qosmio x505

Tags: internet

I'm helping a friend with installing Ubuntu on his Toshiba Qosmio x505 64-bit laptop (natively runs Windows 7 64-bit). He has Comcast cable internet, the same service and routed as we do. We use Ubuntu with it with absolutely no problems, ever.

I have been trying to install software, but to no avail as every minute or so, the internet drops out and comes back up, causing an error in any installation. This is the case on both wireless AND wired (ethernet) connections.

What are the steps I need to take to solve this problem? (Please on't close on account of "duplicate" - I am looking for a hardware specific answer, here. Other solutions aren't working.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem. With this particular model (and probably some others), run the following lines in Terminal...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then restart.